# How to keep the full path with rsync?

Tags: backup, rsync, directory, path

When backing up with rsync, How do I keep the full directory structure?

For example, the remote server is **saturn**, and I want to backup **saturn**'s **/home/udi/files/pictures** to a local directory named **backup**.

I want to have (locally) **backup/home/udi/files/pictures** rather than **backup/pictures**.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Use the `-R` or `--relative` option to preserve the full path.

Comment: just noting: using it with `--remove-source-files` will work like **moving** the file, but with the whole path

Answer (score 20):

Another common related use case it to keep a selected part of the directory tree with `/./`, e.g. if you wanted:

```
/home/udi/files/pictures
```

to go to:

```
backup/files/pictures
```

you can write:

```
rsync --relative /home/udi/./files/pictures backup
```

The magic `/./` gets specially parsed by `rsync` before it passes that path to the system calls, and tells it where to start creating directories from. The `/./` means nothing for other POSIX utilities in general, e.g. the path `a/./b` is the same as `a/b` in POSIX.

Answer (score 2):

With the Cygwin Windows rsync, and assuming the remote rsync is pointing to the root, I'd do:

```
rsync -vtrz --delete server::rsyncid/home/udi/files/pictures /cygdrive/d/backup/home/udi/files
```

That will put the contents of the remote pictures directory in /backup/home/udi/files/pictures. Presumably the syntax under unix would be similar.

JR

Comment: It is not useful because we need to reproduce the whole directory hierarchy on the local side before executing the rsync command.

Answer (score 0):

You can make changes in cron due to when you want to start rsync

rsync -avz -e ssh ruser@rserver:/home/udi/files/pictures/* /backup/pictures/

also you may add ssh key to remote server connect without passwd